# How to hide only the loading overlay

Tags: typescript, ag-grid-angular

I have an ag-grid-angular component defined in an .html.  I have defined a component for the loadingOverlayComponent attribute.  The problem is that there are occasions when the loading indicator does not clear even after loading all of the data.

The grid API provides a method showLoadingOverlay and showNoRowsOverlay but only a hideOverlay method.  I only want to hide the loading overlay.  If there are no rows, I don't want to hide that overlay.  Will the hideOverlay call hide both?  I will invoke the hideOverlay method from the dataRendered method.

Answer (score 0):

Do a check in the dataRendered method for the number of data points contained in the grid.  If non-zero, then don't call the hideOverlay.